# Replace with regular expression using Batch (Windows)

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, replace, find

is it possible to use regular expression for search and replace for a specific text file? I have a text file located C:\content.txt

inside text there is google link

https://www.google.com/

i need a batch (.bat) script which can replace `<https://www.google.com/>` to `[abc]https://www.google.com/[/abc]`

here is the notepad++ regex replace

`Find What:    .+(.google\.com).+
Replace with:  [abc]$0[/abc]`

Comment: there is no buil-in support for that. Take the help of Powershell, VBS or google for `jrepl.bat`

Comment: Using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - `call jrepl "<(https://www.google.com)/>" "[abc]$1[/abc]" /f "c:\content.txt" /o -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Regex in vbscript with a batch file like this code :
You can see [Regex Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/tmoZ4W/2/)

```bat
@echo off
Mode 85,20 & color 0A
Title Replace String using Regex with vbscript
Set "InputFile=C:\Test\content.txt"
Set "OutPutFile=%~dp0NewContent.txt"
echo(
:: To show Results on screen of console
Call :Search_Replace "%InputFile%" CON
:: To write Result in new file
Call :Search_Replace "%InputFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
echo(
echo Press any key to show the results in a new file :
echo "%OutPutFile%"
pause>nul
Start "" "%OutPutFile%" 
echo(
echo Did you want to update and replace all in your original file "%InputFile%" ?
Pause>nul
Move /Y "%OutPutFile%" "%InputFile%">nul
Start "" "%InputFile%" & Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Search_Replace <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Function Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = "%~1" 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo strPattern = "(\x22<|<)([\s\S]*?)(/>\x22|>| />\x22| />| \x22>)"
    echo strReplace = "[abc]$2[/abc]"
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    echo strResult = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace^)
    echo Search_Replace = strResult
    echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For example if the content of your file `C:\Content.txt` looks something like that :

> ```
> "<https://www.google.com />"
> <https://www.google.com>
> "<https://www.developpez.net/>"
> <https://www.developpez.net />
> "<https://www.bing.com/>"
> "<https://www.bing.com />"
> "<https://stackoverflow.com/>
> <https://stackoverflow.com/>"
> <https://stackoverflow.com />
> "<https://stackoverflow.com />"
> ```

After Replace with Regex should be like that :

> ```
> [abc]https://www.google.com[/abc]
> [abc]https://www.google.com[/abc]
> [abc]https://www.developpez.net[/abc]
> [abc]https://www.developpez.net[/abc]
> [abc]https://www.bing.com[/abc]
> [abc]https://www.bing.com[/abc]
> [abc]https://stackoverflow.com/[/abc]
> [abc]https://stackoverflow.com[/abc]
> [abc]https://stackoverflow.com[/abc]
> [abc]https://stackoverflow.com[/abc]
> ```

Comment: thank you worked perfectly. could you please help me one more replace
content.txt has:
`https://example.com/file/casdqwe/test.rar`

output:
`test.rar`

notepad++ regex replace is:

`Find What:  https://example\.com[^\s\[\]<'\"]+/([^\s\[\]<'\"]+)
replace with:  $1`

Comment: @firekid2018 Did you mean like [this Regex](https://regex101.com/r/tgNza6/1/)

Comment: yes please. i tried `echo strPattern = "(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)[^\s\[\]<'\"]+/([^\s\[\]<'\"]+)"` but getting error. thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: @firekid2018 Try this instead `echo strPattern = "(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(.+)[^\s\[\]<]\/([^\s\[\]<].+)"`

Comment: thank you so much, works perfectly. current  script works fine for my work. however just an option: can we edit the original C:\Test\content.txt and save the output to C:\Test\content.txt

Comment: @firekid2018 Did you mean that you want to overwrite your original file with replacements directly and without asking questions ?

Comment: yes is it possible to overwrite the original file and replace directly? no need any questions or confirmation. and can we set multiple file replacement. like `C:\Test\content.txt` `C:\Test\content2.txt`

Comment: @firekid2018
It is better to ask a new question and include properly formatted [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you've written and which exhibits an issue and Refer to this question . 
Include with it sufficient information, for us to replicate your environment and the problem and we will try to assist you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use pseudo-regex with command [FINDSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr).

In the below example, for each line in file "content.txt" we check if it contains regex and replace the link. Then you can redirect output to a new file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "REGEX=.*.google\.com..*"
FOR /F %%I IN (content.txt) DO CALL :REPLACE "%%I"
EXIT /B 0

:REPLACE
SET "LINK=%~1"
ECHO "%LINK%" | FINDSTR /R "%REGEX%" > nul && SET "LINK=[abc]%LINK%[/abc]"
ECHO "%LINK%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Output :

```
"[abc]<https://www.google.com/>[/abc]"
"<https://www.bing.com/>"
```

Redirect output and replace file :

```
test.bat > output.txt
move output.txt content.txt
```

Comment: FINDSTR outputs matching lines - it cannot modify lines as is required by the OP

Comment: @Baptistou no, that is redirecting to a new file, OP wants to "Replace" in the same file.

Comment: In batch you cannot read and write a file line per line at same time. First you need to read the entire file and modify content, then you can replace the existing file by the new content, which gives the same result.