# Replace with regular expression using Batch multiple text (Windows)

Tags: regex, powershell, batch-file, replace, vbscript

I have three text file.

`C:\content1.txt
C:\content2.txt
C:\content3.txt`

text file contains random links

`https://example2.com/file/casdqwe/test1.rar
https://example2.com/file/casdqwe/test2.rar
https://example5.com/file/casdqwe/test3.rar`

i want to remove the the domain names and save the last part only. output

`test1.rar
test2.rar
test3.rar`

and save it in original file no need any confirmation.

notepad++ regex replace work but i am not sure how to do it in 
using Powershell/VBS script any will work fine.

`Find What:  https://example\.com[^\s\[\]<'\"]+/([^\s\[\]<'\"]+)
Replace with:  $1`

and powershell i have something like that

`(Get-Content -path C:\content1.txt -Raw) -replace "https://example2.com/file/asdcb6af26/test.rar" -replace "https://example2.com/file/(.*)\/(.*)", '$2'`

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck? We've got to know more if we're going to help you out.

Comment: i explain my problem. it's only one replacement job which i stuck from start. the replacement which i know won't help much. but anyway i added which i know. i have like below beginner knowledge how to create batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to your [previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336784/replace-with-regular-expression-using-batch-windows?answertab=active#tab-top), you can give a try for this batch file that use Regex in vbscript.

```
@echo off
Mode 85,35 & color 0A
Title Replace Multi String using Regex with vbscript into Folder with text files
Set "Source_Folder=C:\test"
Set "Backup_Folder=%userprofile%\Backup_Contents\"
Rem :: Just make a backup of your folder and its contents if something went wrong!
If Not Exist "%Backup_Folder%" XCopy "%Source_Folder%" "%Backup_Folder%" /D /Y /E /F >%~dp0BackupLogFile.txt
Set "VBSFILE=%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" & Call :CreateVBS
Set "TmpFile=%Temp%\%~n0.tmp"

for /R "%Source_Folder%" %%f in (*.txt) do (
    echo( ------------------------------------------
    echo  Replacing Contents of "%%f"
    echo( ------------------------------------------
    Call :Search_Replace "%%f" "%TmpFile%"
    Move /Y "%TmpFile%" "%%f">nul
)
If Exist "%VBSFILE%" Del "%VBSFILE%"
Timeout /T 3 /NoBreak>nul & Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:CreateVBS
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Function Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = "%~1" 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo strPattern1 = "(\x22<|<)([\s\S]*?)(/>\x22|>| />\x22| />| \x22>)"
    echo strReplace1 = "[abc]$2[/abc]"
    echo strPattern2 = "(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(.+)[^\s\[\]<]\/([^\s\[\]<].+)"
    echo strReplace2 = "$3"
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern1
    echo strResult1 = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace1^)
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern2
    echo strResult2 = oRegExp.Replace(strResult1,strReplace2^)
    echo Search_Replace = strResult2
    echo End Function
)>"%VBSFILE%"
Exit /b 
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Search_Replace <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
Cscript /nologo "%VBSFILE%" < "%~1" > "%~2"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Use these simple powershell commands:

```
(Get-Content C:\content1.txt) -creplace '(?s)^.*/', '' | Set-Content C:\content1.txt
(Get-Content C:\content2.txt) -creplace '(?s)^.*/', '' | Set-Content C:\content2.txt
(Get-Content C:\content3.txt) -creplace '(?s)^.*/', '' | Set-Content C:\content3.txt
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that maybe,

```
\bhttps?:\/\/.*\/
```

simply replaced with an empty string might work just fine.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/875U0Y/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/875U0Y/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---